# Only make a microservice accessible from another microservice

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, aws-cli, amazon-vpc

I have business requirement where I have one microservice to be available through internet and that microservice (A) calls another microservice (B). B should not be directly accessible to internet, only A should be able to call the APIs of B. How can I achieve this by VPC configuration.

I have read about putting one instance in public and one in private. But I am still not sure how to go about it.

Comment: You should check out `security groups`

Comment: Are the microservices running on Amazon EC2 instances? Are they on separate instances, or the same instance? Please Edit your question to describe more of your architecture.

Comment: you need to mention which services are you using ? If it's in private subnet then you can use internal load balancers to access private subnet services.